# Deploying a Grails app to a running Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

Our Tomcat instance runs lots of different webapps : mostly Struts/Struts2 but with the odd Grails app thrown in.

If I need to update a Struts app, generally I'll just copy over the tree from my development machine and the app restarts when the web.xml updates.

With Grails it seems a lot more problematic. Copying the tree and having the app restart almost never works ... apparent missing classes, database connection errors, etc. The only thing that I've found definitely works is stopping tomcat completely, updating the application, and restarting tomcat. The apparent missing classes are no longer missing and database connections are fine with no change of any code. However, this obviously takes all the other applications down too.

Has anyone else seen similar issues? Is there a trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying the tree to the application server [is discouraged](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/deployment.html).
A preferable way is to package your Grails application as WAR:

```
# grails war
```

Or if you [configured maven](http://grails.org/Maven+Integration):

```
# mvn clean package
```

This makes sure that the 'production' environment is set.

Then you can [deploy the WAR file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) and restart the webapp using the [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) if [`autoDeploy`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment) is disabled or not working properly.

Comment: From reading those links it appears that you can *only* deploy a Grails app to a running tomcat if autoDeploy=true. If it's false, you have to restart tomcat anyway. I was using -Dgrails.war.exploded=true. Seems odd to offer this command-line option and yet discourage deploying in this way.